# Returning [object , Object] instead of correct JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here is my function

```
function getRecords(){            
    $.getJSON( "viewcustomers.php", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<td>" + val + "</td>" );
            alert(items);
         });
    });
}
```

The data present in viewcustomers.php is below:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"ali","cnic":"01","address":"nipa","email":"301","phone":"luxairy "},{"id":"2","name":"raheel","cnic":"1234567","address":"abc flat","email":"raheel@gmail.com","phone":"0342"},{"id":"5","name":"Raheel","cnic":"123-4567-45","address":"Gulshan block 13-c","email":"raheel@gmail.com","phone":"03422301775"},{"id":"4","name":"zain","cnic":"12345678","address":"f.b area","email":"zain@gmail.com","phone":"7894561"},{"id":"6","name":"Raheel","cnic":"123-4567-45","address":"Gulshan block 13-c","email":"raheel@gmail.com","phone":"03422301775"},{"id":"7","name":"Ali","cnic":"123456786","address":"nipa","email":"ali@gmail.com","phone":"1234568"},{"id":"8","name":"Waqas","cnic":"123456748","address":"F.b area","email":"waqas@gmail.com","phone":"1234568"},{"id":"9","name":"Owais","cnic":"1234567","address":"Fb area","email":"owais@gmail.com","phone":"12345678"}]
```

But when i am running my jquery function it is giving me [object Object] instead of the above key values.

Comment: That is the result of `.toString()` on an object. Try using the console via `console.log()`.

Comment: Never use `alert` for debugging purposes. Use `console.log()` as already stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `item` is actually an `array`. And you are pushing the values inside it from the JSON. So in order to view it in a string format,

You have to use,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(items));
```

---

While making a deeper look at your JSON, You are traversing on each objects, So you should Stringify those object while inserting into the array like,

```
items.push( "<td>" + JSON.stringify(val) + "</td>" );
```

Comment: I didn't get you, but I'm sure I am gonna learn some thing from you.

Comment: because when `"<td>" + val + "</td>"` is evaluated `val` is an object so the string concatenated value will be `<td>[object Object]</td>` instead of the json string

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, I have updated accordingly after seeing OP'S JSON. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: i did the stringfy and in my console it is showing me 9 times array

Comment: @Raheel Just place the alert out of that loop.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy its returning me keys and values while i have given only val?

Comment: @Raheel So you only need to insert values into that array.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes i want to create a new row for each array..but i need only values to be enterd in td

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the purpose is to make a grid of data.. so 1st record makes a new tr and enter all values in td of 1st row and so on

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you saved me :D Thank yousoooooooooo much

Answer (score 3):

Because the to string implementation of object returns `[object Object]`, you can use the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to handle this. For old browser you have to include a polyfil like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

```
items.push( "<td>" + JSON.stringify(val) + "</td>" );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w5D6J/) - look at the browser console

---

**Update**

It should be simple if you use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var items = $.map(data, function (obj) {
    return "<tr>" + $.map(obj, function (val) {
        return '<td>' + val + '</td>'
    }).join('') + "</tr>";
});
console.log(items.join(''));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8FeLQ/)

Comment: I have ran into anoter problem:

I made my code changed to 
'code'
    function getRecords(){            
            $.getJSON( "viewcustomers.php", function(data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                  items.push(JSON.stringify(val));
                  console.log(items);
                });
              });
        }
'code'

and in my console it is return the json 9 times..